# Error using openssl with socat - SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small

Tags: encryption, openssl, ssl, tunneling, socat

### Short Version of Question

Assuming the existence of the relevant files, why does the following sequence of commands not work?

```bsh
socat tcp-listen:10001,fork exec:'/bin/cat' &
socat openssl-listen:10002,fork,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt tcp:localhost:10001 &
socat tcp-listen:10003 openssl-connect:localhost:10002,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt &
socat stdout tcp:localhost:10003
```

---

### Long Version of Question

I'm trying to use `socat` with `openssl` as described by the following documents:

- [Example for OpenSSL Connection Using Socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssl.txt)
- [Securing Traffic Between two Socat Instances Using SSL](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html)

For context, I'm running socat version 1.7.2.4+sigfix and OpenSSL version 1.1.0f on Debian 9.

Before proceeding to try out `openssl`, I first use `socat` by itself as a sanity check. I start one `socat` instance as an "echo server", use two intermediate `socat` instances (i.e. a second and third instance) to create a tunnel, and then a fourth instance as a "client" to send data to the original process via the tunnel. Here is an example of the commands that I ran:

```bsh
socat tcp-listen:10001,fork exec:'/bin/cat' &
socat tcp-listen:10002,fork tcp:localhost:10001 &
socat tcp-listen:10003,fork tcp:localhost:10002 &
socat stdout tcp:localhost:10003
```

This works as expected - text entered to the terminal is echoed back to the console. A sample session looked something like the following:

```
user@host:~$ socat tcp-listen:10001,fork exec:'/bin/cat' &
[1] 1001

user@host:~$ socat tcp-listen:10002,fork tcp:localhost:10001 &
[2] 1002

user@host:~$ socat tcp-listen:10003,fork tcp:localhost:10002 &
[3] 1003

user@host:~$ socat stdout tcp:localhost:10003
hey
hey
```

Having verified my sanity, I proceeded with the certificate and key generation process.

First I generated a server key and self-signed certificate:

```bsh
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -x509 -days 3653 -out server.crt
cat server.key server.crt > server.pem
chmod 600 server.key server.pem
```

Then I generated a client key and self-signed certificate:

```bsh
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client.key -x509 -days 3653 -out client.crt
cat client.key client.crt > client.pem
chmod 600 client.key client.pem
```

Finally I tried setting up the same tunnel as before, but using OpenSSL encryption:

```bsh
socat tcp-listen:10001,fork exec:'/bin/cat' &
socat openssl-listen:10002,fork,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt tcp:localhost:10001 &
socat tcp-listen:10003 openssl-connect:localhost:10002,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt &
socat stdout tcp:localhost:10003
```

This does NOT seem to work and after executing the last command I get the following error:

```
YYYY/mm/dd HH:MM:SS socat[pid1] E SSL_connect(): error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small
YYYY/mm/dd HH:MM:SS socat[pid2] E SSL_accept(): error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Here is what an example session looked like:

```bsh
user@host:~$ socat tcp-listen:10001,fork exec:'/bin/cat' &
[1] 1001

user@host:~$ socat openssl-listen:10002,fork,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=client.crt tcp:localhost:10001 &
[2] 1002

user@host:~$ socat tcp-listen:10003 openssl-connect:localhost:10002,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt &
[3] 1003

user@host:~$ socat stdout tcp:localhost:10003
2018/08/22 23:43:30 socat[1005] E SSL_accept(): error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
2018/08/22 23:43:30 socat[1003] E SSL_connect(): error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small
[3]+  Exit 1                  socat tcp-listen:10003 openssl-connect:localhost:10002,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt
```

Follow the advice of user [dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085) I tried using the `openssl s_client` command as follows:

```bsh
openssl s_client -cipher 'DHE:!EXPORT:!LOW' -connect localhost:10002
```

This produced error output which contained the following:

```
socat[pid] E SSL_accept(): error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1460:
```

Comment: (fixed) What versions of socat and openssl(lib) and how built? According to http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/contrib/socat-secadv7.html socat before 1.7.3.1 or 2.0.0-b9 defaulted to a 1024-bit tmpdh that wasn't actually prime -- but OpenSSL client doesn't catch nonprimality and I can't find a version that should reject 1024-bit unless someone has tweaked the build. If you have openssl (commandline) 1.0.2+ try `openssl s_client` to your server (add `-cipher 'DHE:!EXPORT:!LOW'` if needed to get it to negotiate DHE) and see what the output says for 'Server Temp Key:'

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the suggestions. I updated my question as you suggested. I'm running socat version 1.7.2.4+sigfix and OpenSSL version 1.1.0f on Debian 9. I got what appears to be the same error (dh key too small) when using the `openssl s_client` command.

Comment: dh key too small: see https://weakdh.org/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for the link, but I'm not sure what (specifically) to do with that information. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Generate a new DH params file, as explained in link above, that is `openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048` and then launch socat with `dhparams` parameter pointing to the file you just created.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed 1.1.0 s_client no longer outputs the info after this error, but I think the version was enough to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you sure *socat* is using OpenSSL 1.1.0? Upstream (from socat.org) 1.7.2.4 source (released in 2014) is not compatible with OpenSSL 1.1.0 (released in 2016) which made significant API changes. Check `ldd $(which socat)`. Are (both) your socat and OpenSSL from standard repositories, other builders/packagers, or built from source?

Anyway, although "what's new" doesn't say so and assuming whatever the "sig" patch is doesn't change it, 1.7.2.4 (upstream) source defaults to 512-bit DH parameters. That is indeed too small -- it was known breakable even before Logjam, and unacceptable to any libssl client from 1.0.1n or 1.0.2b up (both released 2015-06) (and *any* 1.1.0, first released 2016-08).

AFAICS your alternatives are:

- upgrade socat to at least 1.7.3.0 (which in upstream does have 1024-bit); 3.1+ with 2048-bit is even better
- generate, or obtain from somewhere, DH parameters of at least 1024 bits (2048 is better for most clients, including yours, although *some* clients may have trouble such as obsolete versions of Java) and add them to your server's `cert` file.

  You can generate DH parameters with `openssl dhparam $n >file` where `$n` is 1024 or 2048. [If this is too slow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42415/openvpn-dhparam) you can [add `-dsaparam`.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95178/diffie-hellman-parameters-still-calculating-after-24-hours)
- ditto, but put the parameters in a separate file configured on the server. [The manpage](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#GROUP_OPENSSL) says this option is `dhparams=<file>` but the code says it is `dh=` and testing confirms the latter.
- configure the server or client, or both in some combination, so that they don't agree on a ciphersuite that uses DHE; since your server is the one at fault here, personally I would configure only the server. Again the manpage says `cipher` but reality is `ciphers`. Since 1.7.2.4 doesn't set 'tmp_ecdh' parameters, and (AFAICT) it can't use 1.1.0, it won't support ECDHE, which means without DHE your connections will not have Perfect Forward Secrecy. If you can accept that limitation, using `,ciphers='DEFAULT:!DHE'` on the server is a simple fix.

  (1.7.3.0 up do set 'tmp_ecdh' and support ECDHE, which would avoid the problem here even if they didn't default DH-1024 or better, because ECDHE suites are preferred over DHE, so ECDHE would be selected and then the DHE parameters aren't used and don't matter.)